# Provide tips to automate IE11 (Parent/Child relationship) browsers using Selenium and Watir WebDriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, watir

I am automating an application with 2 browsers. I log into the parent browser which allows me to kick off a task in a "child" browser. The "child" communicates to the parent that it has completed it's task back to the parent, once Complete button is clicked within the child browser.

For IE V11, the chatter between the 2 browsers cannot be leveraged.  Meaning when I click on the link to kick off the child browser, browser count = 1 because ieWebdriver is not seeing and cannot interact with the 2nd browser. But this chatter is seen with Firefox and Chrome.

Any tips or suggestions on what I could try? The snippet of the code below returns windowCount = 1 in IE11. but windowCount = 2 in Firefox and Chrome (the result that I want). The customer base for this application uses IE, so unfortunately Firefox and Chrome are not an option.

```
module New_SIT_NOT_A_REAL_TEST
  require 'watir-webdriver'

  my_login_name= name
  my_password= masked
  my_server_url = 'http:server/logon.fcc'

  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.internet_explorer(
      enablePersistentHover: false,
      ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true,
      introduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings: true,
      unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'ignore',
      native_events: 'true'
  )
  b = Watir::Browser.new(:ie, :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
  b.goto my_server_url
  username = b.text_field id: 'username
  username.set my_login_name
  password = b.text_field id: 'pwd'
  password.set my_password
  submit = b.button id:'btnSignon'
  submit.click
  sleep 5
  b.div(class: 'taskAssignment user', index: 0).click
  sleep 1
  windowCount = b.windows.size
  sleep 1 (I put debug line here so that I can read windowCount's value)

end
```

Comment: Setting `introduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings` to true can lead to exactly this behavior. This is especially so if you're crossing a Protected Mode boundary in the navigation of the "child" browser window to its page. This is one of the types of instability you've asked the driver to introduce (hence the name of the capability).

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for this thought. I've retried with setting this settings to false and removing the settings altogether but both bring the same result, no success.  I think that iewebdriver doesn't even see the 2nd window because when I stop my tool after the test, it automatically closes the windows it was working with. It closes the first window but did not close the 2nd window.

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks very much for giving us suggestions. We just figured out the solution. What happened was our ie security settings, some were enabled and some were disabled. We updated our settings so that they are all enabled and now IEWebDriver can recognize the 2nd window and interact with it. Yay!!

Comment: I'll promote my comment to an answer, so you can accept it and future visitors can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The 1 second wait might not be long enough?

Try:

`b.div(class: 'taskAssignment user').when_present.click
Watr::Wait.until { b.windows.size > 1 }
windowCount = b.windows.size`

Comment: Hi titus, thanks for the idea around speed of test but no, this did not work. It threw "timed out" error. I am thinking this has more to do with IE not seeing the complexity of the call calling the 2nd window? Or IE having more security behind the scenes.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue. So, there are definitely 2 windows open after this call, but the driver call only shows one of them? Are you using the 32 bit (recommended) IEDriver?

Comment: Hi titus, we are using the 64 bit iedriver? shoud we try and leverage 32 bit instead? do you think that could be the factor? and you are correct. there are definitely 2 windows open after the call but the driver call only shows one of them. Our machines are 64 bit. so we figured we were in standard with using the 64 bit iedriver.

Comment: The 32 bit IEDriver is recommended by the author, regardless of 64 bit machine. There are definitely differences, and switching windows might be one of them, now that I think about it.

Comment: Hi Titus, thanks very much for giving us suggestions. We just figured out the solution. What happened was our ie security settings, some were enabled and some were disabled. We updated our settings so that they are all enabled and now IEWebDriver can recognize the 2nd window and interact with it. Yay!!

Answer (score 0):

Setting `introduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings` to `true` can lead to exactly this behavior. This is especially so if you're crossing a Protected Mode boundary in the navigation of the "child" browser window to its page. This is one of the types of instability you've asked the driver to introduce (hence the name of the capability).

The correct solution is to manually set IE's Protected Mode settings for each zone. In the browser's options dialog, on the Security tab, make sure the checkbox at the bottom of the dialog is the same value (checked or unchecked) for each zone. It doesn't matter whether the setting is on or off for each zone, only that it's the same value for all zones.